# Obtener datos de un item dentro de una recyclerView al pulsar un botón

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, recyclerview

Lo primero, gracias de antemano, soy neófito en la tecnología Android Studio y estoy implementando una aplicación que contiene una RecyclerView con items personalizados. La cosa es que dichos items tienen botones para llamar por teléfono (por ejemplo), dicho botón se ejecuta y abre la aplicación del teléfono correctamente con un número determinado, pero no sé como hacer que la abra con el número del contacto que contiene el item.

Las clases que tengo son: Contacto, AdaptadorListaContacto y la MainActivity (donde está el oyente del boton). ¿Debería cambiar el oyente a la clase Adaptador y así obtendría la referencia?

Contacto.java

```
public class Contacto {
    private String nombre;
    private int npedidos;
    private String telefono;
    private int tipo; //0:familia; 1:amigo;2:trabajo
    private String email;
    private String direccion;

    public Contacto(String nom, int npedidos, String tel, int tip, String em, String dir) {
        nombre = nom;
        this.npedidos= npedidos;
        telefono = tel;
        tipo = tip;
        email = em;
        direccion = dir;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public int getNpedidos(){return npedidos;}

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public int getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }
}
```

AdaptadorListaContacto.java

```
public class AdaptadorListaContactos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorListaContactos.ContactoViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Contacto> contactos;

    public class ContactoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView lblNombre;
        private TextView lblTelefono;
        private ImageView imContacto;
        private ImageView imFav;

        public ContactoViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            lblNombre = view.findViewById(R.id.lblNombre);
            lblTelefono = view.findViewById(R.id.lblTelefono);
            imContacto = view.findViewById(R.id.imContacto);
            imFav = view.findViewById(R.id.imFav);
        }
    }

    public AdaptadorListaContactos(ArrayList<Contacto> contactos) {
        this.contactos = contactos;
    }

    @Override
    public ContactoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_item_lista, parent, false);
        return new ContactoViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Contacto contacto = contactos.get(position);
        holder.lblNombre.setText(contactos.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.lblTelefono.setText(contactos.get(position).getTelefono());

        if (contacto.getNpedidos() >= 10)
            holder.imFav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            holder.imFav.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        switch (contactos.get(position).getTipo()) {
            case 1: //Cargar imagen de contactos tipo "familia"
                holder.imContacto.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
                break;
            case 2: //Cargar imagen de los contactos tipo "amigos"
                holder.imContacto.setImageResource(R.drawable.building);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactos.size();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java (oyente del boton llamar)

```
public void oyente_btnTlf(View view){
    String telefono = "tel:" + "123456789" ;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(telefono));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Algunas capturas de la aplicación para que me comprendáis mejor:

[image: Recycler view con items]

Lo que pretendo es que al pulsar al botón llamar, llame a dicho número y no al por defecto (123456789). ¿El view que viene como parámetro en el oyente me podría aportar alguna información o darme el valor de los editText quizás?

¡¡GRACIAS!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes crear una interface, por ejemplo:

```
public interface AdaptadorListaContactosListener {

    public void onContactCall(String phoneNumber);
}
```

Luego, en tu clase AdaptadorListaContactos, agregas un nuevo atributo y su setter:

```
public class AdaptadorListaContactos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorListaContactos.ContactoViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Contacto> contactos;
    private AdaptadorListaContactosListener listener;

    public void setListener(AdaptadorListaContactosListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    ...
```

Y también modificar tu onBindViewHolder, previamente agregando el botón btnTelefono a tu "ContactoViewHolder":

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Contacto contacto = contactos.get(position);
        holder.lblNombre.setText(contactos.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.lblTelefono.setText(contactos.get(position).getTelefono());
        holder.btnTelefono.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(listener != null) {
                    listener.onContactCall(contactos.get(position).getTelefono());
                }
            }   
        });
       ...
```

Luego en tu clase donde está tu adaptador, supongamos MainActivity, implementar la interfaz, y en el onCreate, luego de crear tu "AdaptadorListaContactos", agregar a su método setListener (this):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdaptadorListaContactosListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        ...
        adapter = new AdaptadorListaContactos(....);
        adapter.setListener(this);
        ...
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onContactCall(String phoneNumber) {
        String telefono = "tel:" + phoneNumber;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(telefono));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo. Me ha ayudado mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que creo que necesitas es poner tu intent en los items de tu recyclerView, para eso basta con que los pongas en tu metodo

```html
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Contacto contacto = contactos.get(position);
        holder.lblNombre.setText(contactos.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.lblTelefono.setText(contactos.get(position).getTelefono()); 
        holder.iconoTelefono.setOnClickListener{
             // Aqui ponees el intent
             Intent llamar = new Intent(getContext(), Llamar.class);
             llamar.putExtra("TELEFONO", lbl.getText().toString());
             startActivity(llamar);
           }
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a ti también por tu solución es igual de válida que la anterior pero debo marcar la otra por ser más completa y clara y de esa forma ayudar a mas gente. Un saludo!